# Creating Multiple List in foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net, foreach

I have a List which contains columns of data and I want to create n list depending on the number of different Client Code.

| ClientCode | SerialNo | BarCode | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 123 | AC123 | Ok |
| ABC | 1234 | BC123 | Ok |
| ABC | 123 | ABC123 | Failed |
| ABC | 1235 | ABC13 | Ok |
| ADF | 321 | 321DFF | OK |
| ADF | 321 | 332DFF | OK |
| AFG | 1234 | 123ADF | Ok |
| AFG | 1234 | 123ADF | Ok |

And through the ForEachloop
I should have n list(tables) group by from the List.

| ClientCode | SerialNo | BarCode | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 123 | AC123 | Ok |
| ABC | 1234 | BC123 | Ok |
| ABC | 123 | ABC123 | Failed |
| ABC | 1235 | ABC13 | Ok |

| ClientCode | SerialNo | BarCode | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ADF | 321 | 321DFF | OK |
| ADF | 321 | 332DFF | OK |

| ClientCode | SerialNo | BarCode | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AFG | 1234 | 123ADF | Ok |
| AFG | 1234 | 123ADF | Ok |

My final goal is to export them to n differnt excel files, but for now I just wanna get the lists
done first.
These are the things that I have done

```
var ExcelGroupByClient = TotalSN.GroupBy(u => u.Data.ClientCode);
foreach (var Record in ExcelGroupByClient)
{
  //My Codes, which I have no idea of what to write.
}
```

I cant think of a way where I can hold n different list in the ForEach Loop

Thank you guys.

I forgot to mention that my ExcelGroupByClient is actually a Igrouping of Lists.
[Final Solution]

```
 var ExcelGroupByClient = TotalSN.GroupBy(u => u.Data.ClientCode).ToList();
            
            foreach (var Record in ExcelGroupByClient)
            {
                var Datalist = Record.Select(a => new
                {
                    ClientCode = a.Data.ClientCode,
                    ItemCode = a.Data.ItemCode,
                    SerialNo = a.Data.SerialNo,
                    BarCode = a.Data.BarCode,
                    Errors = String.Join(" ", a.Errors)
                });
            }
```

Comment: You could have a `Dictionary<string, List<ClientCodeObj>>` so that the key is the client code, and the value is the list of objects. When you encounter a new key, instantiate a new List for the dictionary entry. When you encounter a key that exists, insert it into the appropriate list.

Comment: @Jasen, Dont quite get it, do you mind elaborate further with an example? Thanks!

Comment: @tymtam, Its like a 2d sting with` TotalSN={""ClientCode:ABC",SerialNo:123","BarCode:ABC123:Remarks:failed","ClientCode:ABC",SerialNo:123","BarCode:ABC123:Remarks:failed""}`  Something like this I believe

Comment: Do not edit your solution into your question. Post your own answer instead

Comment: As posted, your "solution" doesn't do anything. You can skip the foreach if you use the overload of GroupBy  that is `GroupBy(x => x.SomeKey, (k,rs) => ...)` - the `rs` there is the same as the Record in your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You posted your solution into the question, you should post an answer instead. Just wanted to point out you can merge your foreach into the GroupBy because GroupBy has an overload that takes a lambda that is applied to the output:

```
    var groups = TotalSN.GroupBy(
        u => u.Data.ClientCode,  
        rs => rs.Select(a => new
            {
                ClientCode = a.Data.ClientCode,
                ItemCode = a.Data.ItemCode,
                SerialNo = a.Data.SerialNo,
                BarCode = a.Data.BarCode,
                Errors = String.Join(" ", a.Errors)
            }
    );
```

Whatever you were going to use datalist for is now applicable directly to the IGrouping

```
foreach(var datalist in groups){
  foreach(var thing in datalist)
    ...
}
```

You'll confuse yourself less if you strive to use plural or collection-flavored names for things that are collections and singular names for those that are not. Your `Record` is actually a collection still, so Record.Select reads a bit weird because `Record` is a singular but `Select` operates on collections.

Local variables should have camelCase names -> `record`

Comment: Hi thanks for pointing out, but my foreach loop is doing other tasks which I didnt mention in the question. Thank you so much!

Comment: You would/could still use a loop to process those other things - added an example

Comment: I think its a little bit hard for me to explain what exactly I want, but what you said are true, thanks for correcting me and giving me ideas. I will modified my codes accordingly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a snippet showing how to traverse the grouping:

```
var list = new List<(string ClientCode, int Number)>
{
    (ClientCode: "ABC", Number: 123),
    (ClientCode: "ABC" , Number: 1235),
    (ClientCode: "ADF" , Number: 321 ),
    (ClientCode: "ADF" , Number: 1234 )
};

var byClient = list.GroupBy( x => x.ClientCode);

foreach( var group in byClient)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Group's Key: {group.Key}");
    foreach(var record in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"  ClientCode: {record.ClientCode} Number: {record.Number}");
    }
}
```

This prints

```
Group's Key: ABC
  ClientCode: ABC Number: 123
  ClientCode: ABC Number: 1235
Group's Key: ADF
  ClientCode: ADF Number: 321
  ClientCode: ADF Number: 1234
```